# download S&P 500 data with Google as a data source, instead of Yahoo

Tags: r, quantmod

Not sure if yahoo finances are no longer working, but I have been using google for stock data lately because yahoo public data are unavailable. However, for S&P 500 I used to use the symbol `^GSPC` that used to work with yahoo, but doesn't work with google. I tried the following:

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols('GSPC',src="google")
getSymbols('^GSPC',src="google")
```

Which generates an error message.

Is there a different symbol for google finances that represents S&P 500?

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/149

Comment: I don't think that GSPC ticker is valid.  I can't even find it when I search directly in Google Finance.  The syntax of `getSymbols(...,src="google")` is correct, and works if the ticker is, say, MSFT.

Comment: @lebelinoz what would be the correct symbol for S&P 500?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yahoo Finance is working perfectly fine. For downloading GSPC you can use this:

```
SPX <- getSymbols("^GSPC",auto.assign = FALSE, from = "1980-01-01")
```

For goole as source you can use as below, this is for the stock Johnson & Johnson

```
JNJ <- getSymbols("JNJ",auto.assign = FALSE, from = "1980-01-01",src="google")
```

For the indices though, google does not seem to be working at the moment. For the S&P 500, I see the following ticker in google finance:

```
INDEXSP:.INX
```

Comment: when I try `getSymbols("^GSPC",auto.assign = FALSE, from = "1980-01-01")` I get the error message `Error in download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=", from.m,  : 
  cannot open URL 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=^GSPC&a=0&b=01&c=1980&d=3&e=24&f=2017&g=d&q=q&y=0&z=^GSPC&x=.csv'`

Comment: @Oposum: you need to upgrade to quantmod 0.4-8. Google does not provide S&P 500 index data for download, so `getSymbols` cannot work.

Answer (score 1):

The .INX doesn't work, but if you only care about returns statistics and such, you can use the ETF that tracks the index. It has the ticker SPY.