# I can't get the sp500 data from google finance using quantmod package

Tags: r, quantmod

I cant get the sp500 data fro google finance using `quantmod` package using R.

The stock's web page is:

[https://finance.google.com/finance?q=INDEXSP%3A.INX&sq=sp500&sp=1&ei=OPzYWaqcDtOBsAGDq674BQ][1]

I am using the below code:

```
library(quantmod)
GSPC <- getSymbols(".INX",auto.assign = FALSE, from = "2010-01-01",src="google")
```

However, I am getting the below error:

> Error in download.file(paste(google.URL, "q=", Symbols.name, "&startdate=",  :
>         cannot open URL 'http://finance.google.com/finance/historical?q=.INX&startdate=Jan+01,+2010&enddate=Oct+07,+2017&output=csv'
>       In addition: Warning message:
>       In download.file(paste(google.URL, "q=", Symbols.name, "&startdate=",  :
>   cannot open URL 'http://finance.google.com/finance/historical?q=.INX&startdate=Jan+01,+2010&enddate=Oct+07,+2017&output=csv':
>   HTTP status was '404 Not Found'

I guess it is because of the symbol of the stock. I tried a lot different symbols(it is .INX in the above code). However, I couldn't manage to download the data.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43564516/download-sp-500-data-with-google-as-a-data-source-instead-of-yahoo). In the anwers comments joshua ulrich mentions that google does not provide this index data for download.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thanks a lot @wici for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to get the historical data of all SP500 stocks is by loading the `tidyquant` package.

```
tq_index(“SP500") %>% # get the index components
slice(1:3) %>%  # this example will get you the first 3 SP500 stocks, uncomment this line if you want all 500 stocks
tq_get(get = "stock.prices”)
```

Have a look at one of the very detailed and helpful [`tidyquant` vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyquant/vignettes/TQ03-scaling-and-modeling-with-tidyquant.html) . If you want/need `xts`- objects `tidyquant` offers many ways to switch between `tibble` and `xts`objects so that you get all the functionality of the `quantmod` package if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use **src="yahoo"**. 

Note that the symbol name needs to be switched from **.INX** to **^GSPC**.

```
GSPC <- getSymbols("^GSPC", auto.assign=FALSE, from="2010-01-01", src="yahoo")
GSPC[1:2]
           GSPC.Open GSPC.High GSPC.Low GSPC.Close GSPC.Volume GSPC.Adjusted
2010-01-04   1116.56   1133.87  1116.56    1132.99  3991400000       1132.99
2010-01-05   1132.66   1136.63  1129.66    1136.52  2491020000       1136.52
```